# How to disable code inspections for piece of code?

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-inspection

In PhpStorm I can use tags

```
@codeCoverageIgnoreStart
@codeCoverageIgnoreStop
```

to disable coverage checking for piece of code.

Is there something similar for disabling code inspections for piece of code?

Comment: You mean you want to prevent people from viewing your output code in the browser?

Comment: This is not PhpStorm specific stuff -- it's PHPUnit functionality -- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html

Comment: You can suppress specific inspections for a statement (use Alt+Enter on error/warning and proceed from there) ... or you may prevent specific inspections running for a whole file (via `Inspections` settings and custom scope) .. but you cannot disable all analysis for some custom code block in the middle of the file.